# Unable to use CoSign Api by logging in with a DocuSign sandbox account

Tags: docusignapi, cosign-api

I am trying to use the CoSign digital signature functionality in order to create a demo. I created a sandbox account at the DocuSign but I can't log in in order to use the CoSing SOAP API. As server url I use the https://prime.cosigntrial.com:8080/SAPIWS/dss.asmx and as operation type I use the http://arx.com/SAPIWS/DSS/1.0/signature-field-create-sign.

I am using the example [C-Sharp-User-Management-and-signing](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-signature-appliance-api-recipes/tree/master/dsa-soap/C-Sharp-User-Management-and-signing) from the 
repository [docusign-signature-appliance-api-recipes](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-signature-appliance-api-recipes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a discussion that I had with the DocuSign support team they created a CoSign account for me that works properly with the CoSign web services.

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain a free developer account for the DocuSign Signature Appliance (aka CoSign) via the [DocuSign Signature Appliance Developer Center.](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/dsa)

Answer (score 0):

What is the email you've registered to the DocuSign DSA developer's portal? I would like to check that your account in prime.cosigntrial.com is properly set.
Aviv